# curl, sed // Anybody know better way to pull info from web and process?

Tags: linux, curl, sed, web, web-scraping

I wanted to see the rate at which patent attorneys and patent agents registered at the US Patent & Trademark Office. The USPTO offers a .zip file of data on attorneys and agents, but, strangely, does not provide the dates of registration in the .zip file. These dates are only given on the USPTO's web site under each attorney or agent.

To pull down the dates, I used the following:

```
curl -q https://oedci.uspto.gov/OEDCI/details.do?regisNum=[25560-69398:500] | sed -e 's/<[^>]*>//g' | sed -n -e '/Registered/,/nbsp/p' -e '/Registration/,/nbsp/p' | sed -e 's/&nbsp;//g' > dates.txt
```

I only needed so much data to establish the trend, so I chose to pull registration dates for every 500th attorney/agent.

I ended up with a file containing a little more information than I needed (e.g., I didn't need the headings, just the registration numbers and dates), but the file was small enough to hand edit and subsequently plot.

Question: Is there a better and/or easier way to accomplish what I set out to do here? For example, it would be really nice to not hand edit anything, and directly produce columnated data for plotting.

Caveats:
1) Some attorneys have two registration dates, one for when they registered as an agent, and one for when they registered as an attorney. I only need the first date, and I had to hand edit out second dates.
2) Some registration numbers do not exist. In my data set, using the command(s) above, if a registration number does not exist, it was skipped.

Thanks!

Comment: There are lots of ways sure, but I would write a script in your favorite language (perl is really good for this type of work)

Comment: Those are some pretty big caveats. Consider reimagining your process and store you data into an open source database. Even if you can solve this problem using limited tools, then you're sending the message that 'I can always do it quick and dirty', but then you're assigned a project that would be Q&D in a database, but, surprise, you wind up having to implement a db using sed/awk/perl. If you're certain it will never grow past this, then keep looking. Otherwise may be time to reconsider your approach. In any case, good luck!

Comment: Do you mean quiet/silent? `-q` is for `wget`. `-s` is for `curl`.

Comment: Of course, in an ideal world, the site would offer an official, documented, free JSON feed rather than a silly zip file. Scraping is never going to be reliable, robust, or sustainable.

Answer (score 0):

curl (or a similar tool) and regexes may get you a long way for quick and dirty solutions, but as you know by now they're not right for heavy duty stuff.

What you need is a scraper, which will help you automate all the steps in processing the web pages; or at least a full fledged html parser to reliably extract information from the (hopefully reasonably well structured) page data. There are many around for almost every popular language, so the answer actually depends on which language you're more confortable with. If you're into Python, for example, `scrapy` is a well know full scraper solution. `bs4` has a nice interface to handle data extraction.

Answer (score 0):

If you can run python code then I can highly recommend using [Beautiful Soup](http://www.crummy.com/software/BeautifulSoup/).

Answer (score 0):

If you can run Python, have a look at [html5lib](http://code.google.com/p/html5lib/).